# How Do I Remove Emoji and Special Characters Using Vim?

Tags: mysql, json, vim

I have a large text document 1Gig+ and I am trying to import the data into a MYSQL database. Now I go through the process and I receive the following Error

```
OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\x91\\xBD T...' for column 'copyright' at row 24")
```

Now from what I can gather this is an emoji that is present in the values. With the file size being so big I am using VIM to actually open the document for editing, the problem is however that when I search for the above values I can't find them anywhere in the text document.

Am I doing something wrong or is there a better approach?

Thanks

Comment: is the CHARSET of the field "copyright " UTF8 ? if not change it

Comment: It is set to UTF8 but I still get the error. Is there a way using the command line to go through a .txt file and remove all the emjoi symbols?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it simple with sed

The sample will change your code to :-)

```
sed 's/\\\\xF0\\\\x9F\\\\x91\\\\xBD/:-)/g' yourfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

and this will change all 4 Byte Codes

```
sed 's/\\\\x[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\\\\x[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\\\\x[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]\\\\x[0-9A-F][0-9A-F]/:-)/g' x.txt
```